# creating a spread sheet with python

Tags: python, python-module

I had a txt file with content as shown below:
**'marks:  40,66,34,88,70**'
i want to make a **spread sheet** with the **content of txt file**. (illustrated with referrence to 1 txt file, supposing to handle many).
is there any module to handle spreadsheets? how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://sourceforge.net/projects/pyexcelerator/

can be used to create Excel files easily. Check out the examples from the examples folder
within the source tree.

Comment: pyexcelerator is a good option but it isn't well documented. if you could mention how to add data to cells of an existing spreadsheet it will be a great favor. (i tried but didn't worked)

Answer (score 1):

The [`csv`](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) module can export in a format that can be read by nearly all spreadsheet programs with little difficulty.  It's not really clear from your question what you want to put in such a file, though.

Comment: what i want to do is download individual results and make a spread sheet of the results of students of a whole class. I know how to get data from internet and make a text file as i mentioned (individually), but i dont know how to create spreadsheets with python.

Answer (score 0):

My personal preference: 
[For writing Excel Files](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlwt)
[For Reading Excel Files](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd)
[Just go here.](http://www.python-excel.org/)

This uses pypi. So it's even better!

Answer (score 0):

The csv module can do  your spreadsheet lifting.

Assuming you have the file contents read in, here is the relevant spreadsheet creation:

```
import csv

outfile = open('output.csv', 'wb')

# Done for example, a list will need to be created for each row of your spreadsheet.
filecontents = [marks,40,66,34,88,70]

fileWriter = csv.writer(outfile, dialect='excel')
fileWriter.writerow(filecontents)
outfile.close()
```

Of course, there will be additional reading files and loops to write more than one row to the csv file, this is just a basic example.